# Proving or disproving $\{\{a\},b\}=\{\{c\},d\}\iff a=c \land b=d$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> Prove/disprove: $\{\{a\},b\}=\{\{c\},d\}\iff a=c \land b=d$

I know the LHS isn't like in the definition of ordered sets so it's probably false but I can't find any numbers as counter example, nor the empty set...

Maybe if we'll suppose $a=b$ and $a=c$ but show that $b\neq d$ then $\{\{a\},a\}=\{\{a\},d\}$ but now stating that $a\neq d$ will imply $\{\{a\},a\}\neq\{\{a\},d\}$, so that doesn't work either.

Comment: *I know the LHS isn't like in the definition of ordered sets so it's probably false*.  This is a fairly good piece of intuition to have.  Beware convenient statements.

Comment: It may be worthy to note that $\{b,\{a\}\}=(b,a)=\{\{a\},b\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true, as the same equality holds even in the case that
$$
b=\{c\}\quad\text{and}\quad d=\{a\}.
$$

Answer (score 6):

**Counterexample:** take $a=\{1\},b=\{1\},c=1,d=\{\{1\}\}$.